# How to create an interactive navigation, in a circular design, using HTML, CSS, and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
// JavaScript Document
 
 $('.page').hide();
 
 $(".btns").click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault(); //this method stops the default action of an element from happening.
  
  var $me = $(this); //$(this) references .btns, the object in local scope.
  var $myContent = $($me.attr('href')); //pulls href of page 01, 02, or 03. 
  
  $('.page').hide(); //hides all pages
  $myContent.fadeIn();//fades in clicked href connected to btn
  
  $(".btns").removeClass('selected');//
  $me.addClass('selected');
 });
```

```css
*{
 border-spacing: 0px;

}
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;

} 
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 24em;
    height: 24em;
    padding: 2.8em;
    /*2.8em = 2em*1.4 (2em = half the width of a link with img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    border: dashed 1px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}
.circle-container a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 4em; height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;
}
.circle-container img { display: block; width: 100%; }
.deg0 { transform: translate(12em); }
```

```html
 <div class="body_content">
      <div class="page" id="page_01">
   
        <h2>1. Category 1</h2>
        
  </div>
      </div>
 
    <div class="circle-container">
    <nav class="navigation">
   <a href="#page_01" class="btns deg0" >
       <img id="one" src="imgs/button.png" alt="page01"/>
        </a>
 
    </nav>
    </div>
```

I have a unique situation that I would like to discuss with you all. I am trying to create a web page that has a circular navigation, as shown here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxKUG.png)

Each one of these buttons would display content when clicked, like an in-page link. The JQuery is as shown [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xchz.png)

The concept seems simple enough, force all content to hide, when a user clicks a button, the page content linked to that button shows. It works when the links are inline or block display, but when in a circle, the links don't work, the button content doesn't show. Has anyone worked with a similar issue? Or would anyone have a potential solution? I apologize for the vagueness of the questions but the issue seems multi-faceted. Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should post a code snippet with your code so we can check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you not see the second image? I apologize this is my first post. It's shown as a link. How do I display snippets?

Comment: Indeed this is really confusing. With the requested snippet by JV Lobo, could you provide an exemple of what you need to achieve? Maybe it exist somewhere on https://tympanus.net/codrops/category/playground/

Comment: @TrevorJones you can edit your question and add more information. make sure to add as much information as possible, so you can get help from the community

Comment: Thank you, I apologize it's confusing. Perhaps I can edit my code to provide just one example, try to simplify the process.

Comment: You can include jQuery in your code snippet.  Just select the version from the drop-down menu under options.

Comment: Ok, so as you can see, now if you run the code, the content for class "page" which says "Category 1" is displaying, despite having Javascript setting "page" content to hide. It's a strange disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your jQuery reference is working? I don't see any issue with the code, the click event should fire when you click on the links. Check the console for any errors, I strongly believe jQuery might not get loaded.

Comment: See I thought that too, but then I loaded it with a document ready alert and it fires. Just like a "Hey I'm working" and it displays the message. So strange.